# PowerBI pivot table using matrix, filter one column for values equal to 0, filter other column to values greater than 0

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

PowerBI table has columns Firm, Date, AUM.I created a matrix visual with Firm in row, Date in columns, sum of AUM as values. The matrix produces columns for the previous two months June and July. I would like to filter the June column to only instances that equal zero and July column to instances that are greater than 0. (Essentially did a firm go from zero to a positive value month over month). Then finally sort by highest value in July.

The dataset will update each month to the previous two months so ideally the filtering process would be dynamic.

[image]

Comment: Do you want an M or DAX solution

Comment: @horseyride I'd be happy with either. If you know how to do both would you please share? Is one better from a performance perspective? The initial table is about 2M rows.

Comment: If you're planning on using slicers to filter your data and see dynamic results, you need a measure.

Comment: @Pieter , I am using slices. Can you advise on a measure that would accomplish this goal?